# Project level control over use of autopep8

Tags: eclipse, pydev, autopep8

I have a situation where I have configured the use of autopep8 globally but now I need to disable it for certain projects but not others. Is this possible and, if so, how can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's possible... in the code formatter preferences page (`preferences > pydev > editor > code style > code formatter`), make the selection as you want and click the `save to...` and select to which projects that configuration should be saved for.

Note: this will create a file in the `project/.settings` which you can commit to git so that it's properly used whenever the project is checked out (note that there are other preferences which you can also save to the project which may be interesting -- for instance, `save actions` to have files formatted on save).